# Is it possible to change theme default text color in nuxt.config.js or by defining sass variable?

Tags: sass, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have Nuxt / Vuetify app with following configuration (nuxt.config.js)

```
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/sass/vuetify.sass'],

    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: '#e85730',          
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So I can change primary color (applied eg. to button background). I am also able to change Vuetify variables in ~/assets/sass/vuetify.sass, eg.

```
$body-font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif
```

But I am unable to change theme text color there. For light theme color is compiled to 
`.theme--light.v-application`  with default value `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)`

I can override it with CSS rule and same selector, but I don't like it much. I would rather keep theme changes at one place together (ideally in Nuxt config file or at least as sass variable). Is it even possible.

Comment: which version of vuetify are you using?

Comment: @HardikShah Vuetify 2.3.15

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed via the sass variables `$material-light` and `$material-dark` (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/vuetify/#sass-variables). But for the following button colors it will use always dark; primary, secondary, accent, success, error, warning and info.

```scss
$material-light: (
  'text': (
    'primary': 'yellow'
  )
);
$material-dark: (
  'text': (
    'primary': 'blue'
  )
);
```

Comment: Also there is 'secondary' option inside text (for example: v-card-text uses secondary color)